# Give Universal BaseCommand a custom Icon

Tags: arcgis-engine, c#, visual-studio

If I add ControlsMapZoomInTool like this:

```
AddItem("esriControls.ControlsMapZoomInTool", -1);
```

To a Basic Context Menu I get the magnifying icon in my context menu right next to the words "Zoom In".

Is there a way to add an icon to a custom Universal BaseCommand in ArcEngine?

ArcEngine 10, C#, VS2010

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if ArcEngine is different from desktop. Just set the icon in the master base class and do not set it on the children classes.

Something like:

```
public class UniversalCustomCommand:BaseCommand
{
    public UniversalCustomCommand()
    {
        base.m_bitmap = new Bitmap(GetType(),"path to icon");
    }
}

public class ConcreteCommandA:UniversalCustomCommand
{
    public ConcreteCommandA()
        :base()
    {
        // init other members here
    }
}
```